# Hibernate field with custom type changes, but object not marked as 'dirty' for update

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got a Hibernate model that uses a custom type to represent boolean fields (ie, model has a 'Boolean' object, but the database writes a 0 or 1 to a TINYINT field.  Changing the value of the boolean object from (true to false or false to true) will change the value on the object, but the Hibernate session manager doesn't seem to think the object had any values change, and therefore `save()` does not actually write SQL to the DB.

Do  I need to do something special in my custom type to get it to see changes? I'd prefer that to forcing each object to 'dirty' itself in accessors,  but that's also possible.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions.

1. Hibernate calls equals method to check whether object has been changed or not and before that it calls deepCopy method to get copy of custom object. So in your deepCopy method, create new copy of custom object and implement equals method correctly.
2. Second solution is using mix approach AccessType.FIELD and AccessType.PROPERTY. Although this is not recommended but u can see if it gives u knowledge.

this seems as your mapping should be similar as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TABLE_NAME)
**@Access(AccessType.FIELD)**
public class EntityClass {

  ///---some fields 

  @Column(name = "CustomCol")
  @Type(type = "com.something.CustomColType")
  CustomClass customClass;

  //--getters setters

}
```

When you have custom object in ur class and you modify that object only then it doesn't mark as dirty.

- Solution 1 : update some other attribute with customClass object.
- Solution 2 : put `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on customClass field and provide getters/setters for same. 
  This will override default `AccessType.Field` behaviour that u put on class level.

This issue will not be reproducible if you have `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on class level.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, is there any reason that you're using your custom type instead of Hibernate's built-in boolean type?

```
<property name="some_flag" type="boolean"/>
```

Secondly, no, you don't need to do anything "special" in your custom type but you do need to properly implement its `equals()` and `deepCopy()` methods among others. Can you post the source?

Answer (score 0):

[`save()`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object)) doesn't actually save the object (or it's changes) to the database. It marks it as persistent, i.e. an object that Hibernate thinks is managed. If the object is detached, call [`update()`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#update(java.lang.Object)).

Are you [flushing the Session](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush()) when your work is done? And/or [closing it](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#close())?

You might want to double-check the Hibernate manual on [Modifying Persistent Objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-modifying) (I don't say this to be snippy; I had the same issue with Hibernate myself today - forgot the difference between `save()` and other methods, and also forgot to `flush()` my session).